# Formula for getting next number, incremented by two steps

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there any formula which result would be number B (by given A)?

\begin{array}{c c}
A & B\\
1 & 1\\
2 & 1\\
3 & 2\\
4 & 2\\
5 & 3\\
6 & 3\\
7 & 4\\
8 & 4\\
...
\end{array}

Comment: $B = \lceil A/2 \rceil$, or $B = \lfloor (A+1)/2\rfloor$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about$$B=\frac{2A+1-(-1)^A}{4}$$

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is
$$
B=\frac A2+\frac{1-\cos(\pi A)}4
$$